# Get all featured products collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, featured-product

I am trying to retrieve all the featured product like this in my .phtml block:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                           ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', array(1))
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array(1));
```

But i keep getting an error like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getBackend() on boolean in
>   /var/www/gv/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:816\nStack
>   trace:\n #0
>   /var/www/gv/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1377):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->isAttributeStatic('featured_produc...')\n#1
>   /var/www/gv/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(321):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql('featured_produc...',
>   Array, 'inner')\n#2
>   /var/www/gv/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1440):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter('featured_produc...',

Answer (score 2):

This is tested code on 1.9.x

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('productslider/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', array('eq' => '1'))
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array(1)) ;
        foreach($collection as $product){

            echo '<pre>'; print_r($product->getName()); die('ok');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
<?php
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('featured') //add your featured attribute code here if not created then first create attribute in admin side 
        ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1); //

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

    if($collection->getSize()) {
        foreach($collection as $product) {
            print_r($product);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
               ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
               ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', array('eq'=>1))
               ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:You have to create attribute of named featured

Step 2:

You can Use Below code to get the featured product collection in your phtml

page

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', array('yes' => true))
                        ->load();
foreach ($_productCollection as $key => $product) {
                     echo $product->getId()."<br>";
                     echo $product->getName();
                     }
```